# Metrics for NetBeans 6.9.x

Tags: java, netbeans, metrics

I've been an avid Eclipse user for my Java development for a while, but as of late I'm beginning to enjoy developing using NetBeans 6.9.1 more thanks to the faster (IMHO) code completion and the powerful templates and refactoring tools.

Anyway, the one thing that I'm missing is some tool to analyse my code's Metrics. I found a plugin for Eclipse which gives me a myriad of information, from TLOC to Cyclomatic Complexity and an overriden method counter.

Can anyone recommend a WORKING metrics tool for NetBeans 6.9.1? The one that I have found (Simple Metrics, and RefactorIT) are no longer maintained and won't even install as modules on the current NetBeans platform.

So far all I have been able to find on Google are old, unmaintained projects from 2005 or so...

Thank you!

Comment: I've been reasearching and I've found a pretty good stand-alone solution: SourceMonitor (http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) but I'd still like to see if anyone has developed an intergrated solution for NetBeans.

Comment: did you come across any other metric tools during your research?  I have been looking and not come across any as yet.  I had a look at SourceMonitor and it looks ok but only time will tell.  Thanks Andez

Comment: @Andez - I was able to find anything so I'm just using SourceMonitor now :-S

Answer (score 1):

Good question...

Did you tested the plugin "Simple Code Metrics"?: 
http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=9494

Comment: I tried Simple Code Metrics, as I said in my original question, but it won't run on my version of net beans and it's not maintained anymore as far as I can tell. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

PMD in the Software Quality Environment plugin pack at http://kenai.com/projects/sqe/pages/Home does cyclomatic complexity at least, and probably has some other metrics you may find useful.